# Play store rejected "android:icon" does not exist, but it's present

Tags: android

Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(369737): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f0a0000
AndroidManifest.xml:37: error: ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute value reference does not exist

[image]

[image]

bizarrely, my android manifest is not 37 lines long, but it does have android:icon.

I haven't changed anything in the android native layer recently - I've made changes to react native js code, and ran through my same deployment process of generate signed build to get an APK.

This is a new error and I am confused why it's happening and what it means.

The accepted answer for this related question: [Android - Failed to run aapt dump badging: 'android:icon' attribute: attribute value reference does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814228/android-failed-to-run-aapt-dump-badging-androidicon-attribute-attribute-v) has negative points and does not make sense to me.

The two higher suggested related questions did not have accepted answers.

Comment: Android Studio has ran into some APK generation issues in the recent versions resulting in building corrupted APKs larger or smaller than the actual size. Have you tried cleaning your project, deleting the built APKs and generating a new signed APK?

Comment: I did run gradlew clean and tried invalidate caches, too. I am currently upgrading to the latest Android Studio as I was a major version behind (hasn't been an issue this summer/fall)
Thanks for informing me about APK generation issues!